# Android Phone - Can I set a 3rd Party Dictionary as the Default Dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, kindle-for-android

New to the Android ecosystem.

My phone has a default dictionary: 'Collins English' which I downloaded and installed.

I also have installed a 3rd party dictionary which is superior in many ways (for example has spoken pronunciation, thesaurus, etc)

Is it possible for me to assign the 3rd party dictionary as the default dictionary.

It would be nice if I could also use the 3rd party dictionary in my kindle-App.  But I have a feeling that Kindle uses a proprietary dictionary.

Comment: There are some tutorials online that show how to replace the dictionary file used by the Kindle app by a custom file. Not sure if this trick still works, and anyway it does not allow to use an external dictionary app.